# scheduling post request after 2 minutes in djangorestframework?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

Hello developers I am stuck to post request automatically by using APScheduler in djangoRestFramework
each 2 minutes please help to do it

main problems is pass request in scheduling job.

```
class LogisticsTruckListView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    truck_id = request.data.get('truckListId')
    queryset = LogisticsTruckList.objects.filter(truckListId=truck_id)
    serializer = LogisticsTruckListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    data = serializer.data
    # get vehicle no
    vehicle_no = data[0]['vehicle_no']
    if vehicle_no:
        url = "https://track.cxipl.com/api/v2/phone-tracking/doc-latest-location?vehicleNumber="+vehicle_no
        headers = {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            "authkey": "UB1CNQLKU32LPCFQJ2NGL7YY1E51HYF6"
        }
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

here is my scheduling  job code ..

```
def start():
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
viewSets = LogisticsTruckListViewSet()
scheduler.add_job(viewSets.getTrackingDetails(), 'interval', minutes=1,
                  id='tracking_details__001', replace_existing=True)
scheduler.start()
```

Help me out soon as possible

I want to schedule a task in django rest framework

Answer (score 1):

You can use other libraries for scheduling tasks like **[celery-beat](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)**

Comment: Hii @Gautam Ankul, if this is helpful for you then can you please accept this answer as an accepted answer?